Cant change Angular Materials paginator value after using viewChild signal
I need to change my tables paginators pageIndex and pageSize, my code works well when i use ViewChild, but i want to use signal query, when i use signal query i got this error;
Writing to signals is not allowed in a computed or an effect by default.
///@ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator; -->this works
paginator = viewChild<MatPaginator>('paginator');

_onPaginationChange(event: PageEvent) {
    const previousPageIndex = this.req.pageNumber - 1;
    const previousPageSize = this.req.pageSize;

    this.checkModifiedCellsAndCallback(() => {
      this.req.pageNumber = event.pageIndex + 1;
      this.req.pageSize = event.pageSize;
      this.getTableData();
    });

    // Revert paginator state if the user cancels the action
    if (this.modifiedCells.size > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        paginator.pageIndex = previousPageIndex;
        paginator.pageSize = previousPageSize;
      });
    }
  }


You have to execute the signal method to access the element from the viewChild.
After doing these changes. You might need to call cdr.detectChanges(); since we are modifying the signals inner properties so it's not a proper signal update, so we need to call this, for change detection to fire and the changes to be updated. Mostly this will be needed when changeDetectionStrategy is OnPush.
paginator = viewChild<MatPaginator>('paginator');
cdr: ChangeDetectorRef = inject(ChangeDetectorRef);
_onPaginationChange(event: PageEvent) {
    const previousPageIndex = this.req.pageNumber - 1;
    const previousPageSize = this.req.pageSize;

    this.checkModifiedCellsAndCallback(() => {
      this.req.pageNumber = event.pageIndex + 1;
      this.req.pageSize = event.pageSize;
      this.getTableData();
    });

    // Revert paginator state if the user cancels the action
    if (this.modifiedCells.size > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const paginator = this.paginator(); // <- execute the `viewChild` to access the paginator object.
        paginator.pageIndex = previousPageIndex;
        paginator.pageSize = previousPageSize;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      });
    }
  }


not worked, still this error occurs; Writing to signals is not allowed in a computed or an effect by default. Use allowSignalWrites in the CreateEffectOptions to enable this inside effects. But i didnt set in effect or computed i just directly change property of paginator in a normal method. i can change if i use @ViewChild.

@ocanyldz the problem is not in the code you shared, please share a stackblitz where the issue happens or other code that uses this view child
